# Total memory consumption in linux machine

Tags: centos, memory

i have a question of mem RAM cosumition.

The question is that "htop" show me 6GB or RAM used of 32Gb but i can´t find which process are consuming this amount of memory.

if i run

```
ps -e -orss=,args= | sort -b -k1,1n | pr -TW$COLUMNS
```

and then import this dates tu XLS the total amout of memory is 2,5GB

Comment: Also: [an important read](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the top command

Just type top
then once in hit shift-M to sort by memory.

You will get output like this.

```
top - 10:10:19 up 90 days, 14:32,  1 user,  load average: 0.08, 0.12, 0.11
Tasks:  92 total,   1 running,  91 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.0%us,  2.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 96.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1737376k total,  1690084k used,    47292k free,   279060k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   391192k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
30832 root      39  19  344m  15m 1484 S  0.0  0.9   0:12.26 yum-updatesd      
32095 root      20   0  412m  14m 7788 S  0.0  0.9   2:58.01 httpd             
 3978 apache    20   0  414m  11m 3440 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.98 httpd             
22545 apache    20   0  414m  11m 3440 S  0.0  0.7   0:01.10 httpd             
13648 apache    20   0  414m  11m 3444 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.92 httpd             
  671 apache    20   0  412m 9316 1592 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.99 httpd             
  913 apache    20   0  412m 9304 1588 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.13 httpd
```

Consult the docs and resources for details on the meaning of each column.